# Shisha Ve'arba'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred forty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all answers I consider relevant and interesting.*
- *Accept the what I think is the "best" answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: What's the point in going through all the numbers?

Comment: @Ariel Some members of the community find it fun and interesting, and it frequently leads to exposure of interesting and unexpected Jewish facts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "Gavriel" is numerically equivalent to 246, which in turn is equivalent to a complex combination of the letters of G-d's name (see Sefer haShem, p. 55) and is hinted to in the verse (Breishis 19 24) and G-d rained on Sodom; some commentaries hold that the angel Gavriel is the one that overturned Sodom; see also the verse (Job 9 5) Asher Hufchum bApo ("that he overturned in His anger", referring to the overturning of Sodom), end-letters of these words spell 246.

Answer (score 5):

In **246** BCE ([3515 years after creation](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=165&hilite=)), the Torah was translated into Greek by 72 Chachamim for the emperor Ptolmey. (Megilla 9a)

Answer (score 4):

**246:**

- Mitzvos Aseh that do not have a chiyuv
  Kares.
- Word in Kerias Shema (if you
  include "Emes").
- The [Siman in Yoreh Deah](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%95) that discusses the chiyuv to learn Torah,who is included in the mitzvah, how and what to learn, and the issue of getting paid to learn Torah.

Comment: +1 for _mitzvos ase_ (and I suppose for _sh'ma_ words); not for the _siman_, as there's no assertion of any thing special about that _siman_ (I mean, every number up to, um, whatever is a _siman_ in one of the _turim_).

Comment: That siman is probaly one of the most relevant and controversial simanim in Shulchan Aruch. Learning Tanach, Learning in Kollel,  Women's learning, etc..

Comment: Aside from the controversy, it's got to be by far the most relevant Siman to Judaism.SE!  +1

Answer (score 2):

In 1795 there were 246 Jews living in Odessa

http://www.emanu-el.od.ua/en/jewish-odessa-/history-en.html

Comment: OK, what did you do, just Google 246 and Jewish?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Off-topic, but: The number of passengers aboard [Air France flight 139, June 27, 1976,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Entebbe) is given variously as 246 and [248](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8040).

Comment: no records??```