# Shemona Ve'arba'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred forty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all answers I consider relevant and interesting.*
- *Accept the what I think is the "best" answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

*The Race to Ramach starts now.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hashem* examined each word of the *Tora* 248 times before putting it in the *Tora* (whatever that means), corresponding to the 248 *evarim* (bones or something) of a person ([source](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35934&st=&pgnum=33&hilite=)), which in turn correspond to the 248 words of *sh'ma* ([source](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=187&hilite=)) and *mitzvos ase* (positive commands).

Comment: "248 evarim (bones or something)" - They are body _parts_ (loosely defined). It's a _mishna_ in Ahalos.

Comment: Yeah. It's usually translated "bones" (or "limbs"), but that's incorrect, so I put "bones or something". `:-)`

Comment: @WAF Oholos 1:8

Answer (score 5):

Number of sidereal months it takes for the moon to begin its draconic month at the same sidereal time corresponding to 248 positive commandments, while 365 days in a solar sidreal year correspond to the 365 negative commandments. ([Source](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5759/veschan/oschutz.htm))

Comment: It's not 247 years? (Shame it's one off.)

Answer (score 3):

אברהם = 248 and is mentioned 175 times in Tanach, which is the amount of years he lived.

248 = במדבר

Comment: What happened to no lazy gematria?

Answer (score 3):

The last three words in Shema are repeated, so as to bring the number up to 248. see [here](http://www.torah.org/learning/tefilah/248limbs.html).

Answer (score 2):

The verb עשה is used 248 times in connection with construction of the *mishkan*, from *Sh'mos* 25:8 through 39:43 (exclusive of 32:1 through 33:5, which are about the *egel*), according to *Tol'dos Yitzchak* (commentary of *Rav Yitzchak Karo*, uncle of the *Bes Yosef*) to 39:43.

Answer (score 1):

Off-topic, but: The number of passengers aboard [Air France flight 139, June 27, 1976,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Entebbe) is given variously as [246](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7954) and 248.