# What is considered alone for shma?

Tags: halacha, words, shema, minyan

When saying shma in davening without a minyan, the three words א-ל מלך נאמן are recited. It is done in order to [make up 248 words](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8016/5151) total (with a minyan, the chazzan says ה' א-לוקיכם אמת to get the 3).

With this in mind, what is considered davening alone that *kel melech ne'eman* would be said?

Must you be actually without a minyan, or can you be considered 'alone' even if you're with a minyan, but catching up? Does it make a difference if the chazzan hasn't finished saying shma yet or not?

Comment: I told you that I thought Artscroll shared my conclusion in their *siddur*; apparently, I misremembered. I've definitely seen this somewhere though....will update my answer iyH if/when I find it.

Answer (score 3):

[שלחן ערוך ס"א:ג](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x431)

> בִּקְרִיאַת שְׁמַע יֵשׁ רמ''ה תֵּבוֹת, וּכְדֵי לְהַשְׁלִים רמ''ח
>   כְּנֶגֶד אֵיבָרָיו שֶׁל אָדָם, מְסַיֵּם שְׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר (ב) ה'
>   אֱלֹקיכֶם אֱמֶת, וְחוֹזֵר וְאוֹמֵר בְּקוֹל רָם ה' אֱלֹהֵיכֶם
>   אֱמֶת:‏
>
> In *shema* there are 245 words, and in order to get to 248 words
>   (corresponding to the number of bones in a human body), the prayer
>   leader says "ה' אלוקיכם אמת," by himself, and then repeats it out loud
>   (so that it will count for the congregation).

Rama, there:

> וְיֵשׁ שֶׁכָּתְבוּ דְּכָל הַקּוֹרֵא קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע בְּיָחִיד, יֹאמַר
>   קל מֶלֶךְ נֶאֱמָן (ה) שְׁמַע וְגו', כִּי ג' תֵּבוֹת אֵלּוּ
>   מַשְׁלִימִים הַמִּנְיָן שֶׁל רמ''ח....וְנִרְאֶה לִי מִכָּל מָקוֹם
>   כְּשֶׁקּוֹרֵא עִם הַצִּבּוּר, לֹא יֹאמַר קל מֶלֶךְ נֶאֱמָן, רַק
>   יֹאמַר אָמֵן אַחַר הַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר כְּשֶׁמְּסַיֵּם הַבְּרָכָה,
>   וְכֵן נוֹהֲגִין, וְנָכוֹן הוּא.‏
>
> Some have written that anyone who reads שמע by himself should say "קל
>   מלך נאמן," so that these three words will round out שמע to 248
>   words....I would say that when someone is with a congregation, he
>   should only say אמן (because קל מלך נאמן might replace that אמן right
>   before שמע) -- this is what is done, and it is correct.

My reading of the above is that קל מלך נאמן is not said when one is with a minyan, where the חזן says ה' אלוקיכם אמת, and is said in every other case -- hence **"alone" means where the חזן will not say ה' אלוקיכם אמת before the end of your שמע.**