# Is there a listing of all 248 members of the human body?

Tags: number, parts-of-the-body

There are 248 positive commandments and this is reflected in the commonly stated idea that there are 248 (let's say "members") in the human body (commonly stated as bones). Though how it's translated (bones? limbs? members? other?), is another matter and perhaps for another question.

But I haven't seen a list. I think it is more likely there isn't a list, but I think there might be, and I am interested. Does it exist anywhere and if so, where?

Is there any listing of all 248 members of the human body?

Comment: They are listed in a [_mishna_ in Ahalos](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Oholot.1.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Also see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7997).

Comment: Note that what is well known to you might not be for others. Millions of people read the internet. Please try and source things better.

Comment: Note as well this meta post http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/307/759 about how to ask questions when you know the answer. The summary is: ask it as if you didn't know the answer. This question could do more to follow that guideline.

Comment: is this on topic?

Comment: you should probably check out http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment regarding how to use comments here.

Comment: @DoubleAA the SE system auto-generates a chat link after some back and forth. If you want that earlier, then you or I can create a room for the purpose, for any discussion unsuitable in an edit to a question and 'unsuitable' in comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are listed in the Mishna  Seder Taharoth,   Ohaloth 1:8

A link to an english translation online has been provided by WAF [**here**](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Oholot.1.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

```
30      feet 30 each foot (6 each toe)  
10      ankle 10 each ankle 
2       lower leg 2 in each lower leg   
5       knee 5 each knee    
1       thigh one. Each thigh   
3       hip 3. I guess they're counting only one hip    
11      ribs 11 
30      hand 30 
2       forearm 
2       two in the elbow. 2 elbows  
1       upper arm   
4       shoulder
```

totalling 101 on each side

times two is 202.

plus

```
18      vertebrae   
9       in the head 
8       in the neck 
6       in the chest    
5       openings    

totalling 46
```

**202+46=248**