# How many times does the word "Chesed" (in singular or plural forms) appear in Tanach?

Tags: words, tanach, statistics, chesed-kindness

How many times does the word "Chesed" (in singular or plural forms) appear in Tanach? I've heard somewhere that the number is 248, but I cannot confirm this.

If it is 248, it would be an amazing connection to many other items/gematriot;
(i.e., Number of words in Shema, number of positive commandments, number of limbs, the gematria of "Avraham," the gematria of the "B'tzelem Elokim.") All of which are connected to Chesed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: would you want included words like  חֲסִידָיו? or even הַחֲסִידָה?

Comment: Cf. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7995

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance

Comment: Ok since we've opened plural or variants I'll say the whole thing is Chesed עולם חסד יבנה which is Chesed 72 which is Y YK YKW YKWK as is known Tikunei Zohar 51a-b the Future Song are we there yet NN